# Assign Gridview row values to hiddenfield inside template. Use a button to post the hidden field value to another page

Tags: asp.net, .net, aspxgridview

I have a Gridview control that returns rows from a table called workerID. I return 10 rows at a time and allow paging. What I would like to do is place a `HiddenField` in a template within the Gridview. I want to assign or bind a value from the Gridview control to the `HiddenField`. The value I want to bind is workerID.

I then want to be able to submit the value assigned to the `HiddenField` to another page that that has a `SqlDataSource` with a formfield parameter that is looking for the value of the `HiddenField` to be passed. To do this I also put a submit button in the item template field along side the hidden field. My assumption is that the submit button would post the `HiddenField`value of each row to my second page looking to receive the formfield parameter (Hiddenfield1).

I believe my assumption is wrong and there is some more coding or work that needs to be done. In summary I am trying to bind each row value in a GridView control (value of workerID) and then post that value to another page that will receive it. I find it easy to pass a url value from the gridview but in this case passing a url querystring is not an option.

Page 1 - With the hiddenfield:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="workoutID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource5">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="workoutID" HeaderText="workoutID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="workoutID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="workoutTitle" HeaderText="workoutTitle" SortExpression="workoutTitle" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="UserID" HeaderText="UserID" SortExpression="UserID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="description" HeaderText="description" SortExpression="description" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="exercisenotes" HeaderText="exercisenotes" SortExpression="exercisenotes" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("workoutID") %>' />
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/postfromgridview.aspx" Text="Button" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Page 2  - With SQLdatasource and formfield parameter:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="workoutID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="workoutID" HeaderText="workoutID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="workoutID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="workoutTitle" HeaderText="workoutTitle" SortExpression="workoutTitle" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="UserID" HeaderText="UserID" SortExpression="UserID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="description" HeaderText="description" SortExpression="description" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
</td>
<td>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ 

    ConnectionStrings:SQL2008R2_504887_golivefitnesConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="workout_testing" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:FormParameter FormField="Hiddenfield1" Name="workoutID" Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about a different approach?  Handle the RowCommand event of the GridView on your first page:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataKeyNames="workoutID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource5"
    OnRowCommand="GridView2_RowCommand">
```

Remove the HiddenField, set the workoutID as the CommandArgument for your button, and remove the PostBackURL attribute:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button"
    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("workoutID") %>' />
```

Use that RowCommand event to stuff the workerID value into a Session variable:

```
protected void GridView2_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    int workoutID = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
    Session["selectedWorkoutID"] = workoutID;
}
```

Then, on your other page, chage that FormParameter to a SessionParameter:

```
<asp:SessionParameter Name="workoutID" SessionField="selectedWorkoutID" 
    Type="Int32" />
```